# Access asp element in a repeater via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

**The Scenario:**

I have a form in which I register people. I have a button "Add more people". The repeater has ran 4 times on Page_Load and all the controls is already on the page(they are just hidden). When I click the button I find the first hidden `div` and just show it.

**The Problem:**

Now I need to do stuff with a speciffic element in a speciffic div generated by the repeater (for example change it's class). However I don't know how to access it. Access by Id doesn't work and neither does access by class. I can't do anything from the code behind becaus everything is already on the page. It has to be done in javascript. Any ideas?

**The code:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptOtherPeople" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
                 <h3>Other people</h3>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="GridRow" id="personRow" style="display: none">           
                    <dl>
                        <dt class="form-lbl left">Name</dt>
                        <dd class="form-value left">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" CssClass="mid-inp required" Text="" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="separator"></div>
          </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate> </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

The javascript that shows the next row:

```
 var peopleNum = 1;
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < peopleNum; i++) {
        $(".GridRow").each(function (index) {
            if (index == i)
                $(this).show();
        });
    }
})

function addPerson() {
    peopleNum++;
    $(".GridRow").each(function (index) {
        if (index == peopleNum-1)
            $(this).show();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you be some what clear ?? when will you wish to change the CSS or any other stuff?? We can handle repeater in Jquery

Example:

```
$("[id*=txtFirstName]").change(function () {
         // This displays the text from the Tag element of the button...    
                $(this).css("background", "red");
            });
```

Comment: good answer..but could you explain it a bit more..What is [id*= (I guess its searching the id in page (for each?)

Comment: Yes It will get all the id's in our page which contains string txtFirstName

Comment: It is like Attribute:value.[] represent syntax. Check this link once http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

well you have some options, 1st is using the IDs to find the array of elements like this

```
$($( "input[id*='txtFirstName']" )[i]).addClass("myNewClass")
```

this means all elements that their id contains txtFirstName.

another is select by your grid:

```
$($(".GridRow")[i]).find(".mid-inp").addClass("myNewClass")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
$($(".GridRow")[i]).addClass("Yourclass");
```